# Differentiability and continuity of $f(x)=x^2+\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}+\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}+\ldots \to \infty$

Tags: calculus, continuity

If $$f(x)=x^2+\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}+\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}+\ldots \to  \infty \,,$$ then
choose the correct option:

$(A)$ lim($x \to 0$) $f(x)$ does not exist.

$(B)$ lim($x \to 0$) $f(x)$ exist but $f(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=0$

$(C)$ At $x=0$, $f(x)$ is continuous but not differentiable

$(D)$ $f(x)$ is differentiable everywhere.

Now what I see here is that $f(0)=0$ and when $x \to 0$, then we can apply sum of infinite terms of G.P. as common ratio will be less than $1$ in that case and I got $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ as $1$ which makes the function discontinuous.

Am I correct?

Comment: On essentials, yes. But it looks to me as though $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=1$ not 2. The series seems to sum to $1+x^2$ except at $x=0$ when it sums to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**. From the standard geometric series evaluation, one has

$$
 f(x) =
    \begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x=0$} \\[2ex]
x^2 \cdot \frac1{1-\frac1{1+x^2}}=\color{red}{1+x^2}, & \text{if $x\neq 0$.}
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$ f(x) = x^2\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^k}=\frac{x^2}{1-\frac{1}{1+x^2}}=1+x^2 $$
holds for any $x\neq 0$, since the involved geometric series is convergent ($1+x^2>1$).
However, at $x=0$ we clearly have $f(x)=0$, hence $f$ is a discontinuous function and $\color{red}{(B)}$ is the correct option.